# Equivalent appearence of font in c# and Java

Tags: winforms, fonts, awt

I need to emulate С#'s font drawing in Java. The result is:

```
    Graphics g =this.CreateGraphics();
    Font f = new Font("Courier New", 24, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Document);
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White),0,0,400,400 );
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 100, 200, 100);
    g.DrawString("Hey go!", f, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 100);
```

[image]

I've recalculated font size but java font looks a bit destorted.

```
            Font f = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 24 * 120 / 300).deriveFont((float) (24 * 120. / 300.));
            FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(null, false, true);
            TextLayout textLayout = new TextLayout("Hey go!", f, fontRenderContext);
            Graphics graphics = contentPane.getGraphics();
            graphics.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
            graphics.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            graphics.drawLine(0, 100, 200, 100);
            graphics.setFont(f);
            Color c = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            graphics.setColor(c);
            textLayout.draw((Graphics2D) graphics, 0, 100);
```

[image]

Can I do something to make output look the same?
PS: I've updated the code, since I've found an error.
Rightclick images to see them pixel-to-pixel in your browser.

Comment: Are you using the Large Fonts on the system? (I'm guessing based on the oversized `X` icons in your titlebars; the last time I saw them so malformed was on a system using Large Fonts. Those seem to break brittle assumptions made in many programs...)

Comment: I am using Large Fonts. Switching to standard doesn't solve the problem, though changes C#'s appearance a bit.

Comment: Now after the changes the bottom image looks like you turned off antialiasing.

Comment: Yes, antialiasing is off. Thanx, Howard.

Comment: @stiv If you turn it on it is almost like the upper image.

Comment: @Hovard, no! If I turn it on I get gray pixels http://i.imgur.com/tBaqI.png while C# doesn't have them

Comment: @stiv As said: turn ON antialiasing and turn OFF fractional metrics should be very very close to C#.

Comment: @Howard let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1104/discussion-between-stiv-and-howard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that you render the text twice with some little differences.

```
textLayout.draw((Graphics2D) graphics, 0, 100);
graphics.drawString("Hey go!", 0, 100);
```

First time you use the `TextLayout` and second time directly draw the string. The `TextLayout` uses `fractionalMetrics` as specified by the last parameter in the constructor which the `drawString` method doesn't.

Therefore you draw the string two times with different settings and the result is that the string shows this faint shadow.

Remove the second call to `drawString`, choose whether you like `fractionalMetrics` or not and you'll be just fine.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you, I've found this already. But the problem with pixel-to-pixel equivalency presents :(